# Display 3 pie charts in a Flex mobile View - test case and screenshots attached

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, pie-chart, flex4.6, flex-mobile

I display 3 pie charts for every user of a game in a very simple View (the source code is pasted below).

The charts represent opinions of other players - if the displayed user plays **good**, **fair**, **nice**.

So I fetch the JSON data from a PHP script using 3 URLLoaders and place it into 3 ArrayCollections: `_acGood`, `_acFair` and `_acNice`

**My problem is the layout** - in portrait mode the pie charts have different sizes (probably depending on when which data loads):

[image: portrait]

And in the landscape mode they aren't readable (too small):

[image: landscape]

My intention is actually to display all pie charts "full-sized" and in a Scroller - scrollable vertically (in portrait mode) and horizontally (when in landscape mode).

Here is my current test code - it will work instantly if you place these 2 files into a Flash Builder project -

**Main.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    firstView="views.Home" />
```

**Home.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        viewActivate="startLoading(event)"
        title="Display 3 pie charts">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:ArrayCollection id="_acGood" />
        <s:ArrayCollection id="_acFair" />
        <s:ArrayCollection id="_acNice" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;

            private static const PLAYER_ID:String = 'DE11198';

            private static const STATS_GOOD:String = 'http://preferans.de/rep-json.php?title=good&id=';
            private static const STATS_FAIR:String = 'http://preferans.de/rep-json.php?title=fair&id=';
            private static const STATS_NICE:String = 'http://preferans.de/rep-json.php?title=nice&id=';

            private var _urlLoaderGood:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            private var _urlLoaderFair:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            private var _urlLoaderNice:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

            private function startLoading(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void {
                _urlLoaderGood.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleCompleteGood);
                _urlLoaderFair.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleCompleteFair);
                _urlLoaderNice.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleCompleteNice);

                _urlLoaderGood.load(new URLRequest(STATS_GOOD + PLAYER_ID));
                _urlLoaderFair.load(new URLRequest(STATS_FAIR + PLAYER_ID));
                _urlLoaderNice.load(new URLRequest(STATS_NICE + PLAYER_ID));
            }

            private function handleCompleteGood(event:Event):void {
                var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
                var obj:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data);

                _acGood.removeAll();
                for each (var row:Object in obj.rows) {
                    _acGood.addItem({ label: 'Играет ' + row.c[0].v, data: row.c[1].v });
                }
            }

            private function handleCompleteFair(event:Event):void {
                var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
                var obj:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data);
                _acFair.removeAll();
                for each (var row:Object in obj.rows) {
                    _acFair.addItem({ label: 'Играет ' + row.c[0].v, data: row.c[1].v });
                }
            }

            private function handleCompleteNice(event:Event):void {
                var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
                var obj:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data);
                _acNice.removeAll();
                for each (var row:Object in obj.rows) {
                    _acNice.addItem({ label: 'Общаться ' + row.c[0].v, data: row.c[1].v });
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="portrait"/>
        <s:State name="landscape"/>
    </s:states> 

    <s:layout.portrait>
        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" />
    </s:layout.portrait>
    <s:layout.landscape>
        <s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle" />
    </s:layout.landscape>

    <mx:PieChart id="_good" 
                 height="100%" 
                 width="100%"
                 dataProvider="{_acGood}" >

        <mx:series>
            <mx:PieSeries labelPosition="callout" labelField="label" field="data">
                <mx:fills>
                    <mx:SolidColor color="0x66CC66" />
                    <mx:SolidColor color="0xCC0000" />
                </mx:fills>             
            </mx:PieSeries>
        </mx:series>
    </mx:PieChart>

    <mx:PieChart id="_fair" 
                 height="100%" 
                 width="100%"
                 dataProvider="{_acFair}" >

        <mx:series>
            <mx:PieSeries labelPosition="callout" labelField="label" field="data">
                <mx:fills>
                    <mx:SolidColor color="0x66CC66" />
                    <mx:SolidColor color="0xCC0000" />
                </mx:fills>             
            </mx:PieSeries>
        </mx:series>
    </mx:PieChart>  

    <mx:PieChart id="_nice" 
                 height="100%" 
                 width="100%"
                 dataProvider="{_acNice}" >

        <mx:series>
            <mx:PieSeries labelPosition="callout" labelField="label" field="data">
                <mx:fills>
                    <mx:SolidColor color="0x66CC66" />
                    <mx:SolidColor color="0xCC0000" />
                </mx:fills>             
            </mx:PieSeries>
        </mx:series>
    </mx:PieChart>  

</s:View>
```

**UPDATE:**

My new code with [Scroller](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Scroller.html) still has same usability problems (labels unreadable, pies of uneven sizes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        viewActivate="startLoading(event)"
        title="Display 3 pie charts">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:ArrayCollection id="_acGood" />
        <s:ArrayCollection id="_acFair" />
        <s:ArrayCollection id="_acNice" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;

            private static const PLAYER_ID:String = 'DE11198';

            private static const STATS_GOOD:String = 'http://preferans.de/rep-json.php?title=good&id=';
            private static const STATS_FAIR:String = 'http://preferans.de/rep-json.php?title=fair&id=';
            private static const STATS_NICE:String = 'http://preferans.de/rep-json.php?title=nice&id=';

            private var _urlLoaderGood:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            private var _urlLoaderFair:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            private var _urlLoaderNice:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

            private function startLoading(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void {
                _urlLoaderGood.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleCompleteGood);
                _urlLoaderFair.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleCompleteFair);
                _urlLoaderNice.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleCompleteNice);

                _urlLoaderGood.load(new URLRequest(STATS_GOOD + PLAYER_ID));
                _urlLoaderFair.load(new URLRequest(STATS_FAIR + PLAYER_ID));
                _urlLoaderNice.load(new URLRequest(STATS_NICE + PLAYER_ID));
            }

            private function handleCompleteGood(event:Event):void {
                var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
                var obj:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data);

                _acGood.removeAll();
                for each (var row:Object in obj.rows) {
                    _acGood.addItem({ label: 'Играет ' + row.c[0].v, data: row.c[1].v });
                }
            }

            private function handleCompleteFair(event:Event):void {
                var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
                var obj:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data);
                _acFair.removeAll();
                for each (var row:Object in obj.rows) {
                    _acFair.addItem({ label: 'Играет ' + row.c[0].v, data: row.c[1].v });
                }
            }

            private function handleCompleteNice(event:Event):void {
                var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
                var obj:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data);
                _acNice.removeAll();
                for each (var row:Object in obj.rows) {
                    _acNice.addItem({ label: 'Общаться ' + row.c[0].v, data: row.c[1].v });
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="portrait"/>
        <s:State name="landscape"/>
    </s:states> 

    <s:Scroller 
        width="100%" 
        height="100%"
        verticalScrollPolicy.portrait="on"
        horizontalScrollPolicy.landscape="on">

        <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">

            <s:layout.portrait>
                <s:VerticalLayout />
            </s:layout.portrait>
            <s:layout.landscape>
                <s:HorizontalLayout />
            </s:layout.landscape>

            <mx:PieChart id="_good" 
                         width.portrait="100%"
                         height.landscape="100%"
                         paddingRight="8" 
                         paddingLeft="8" 
                         dataProvider="{_acGood}" >

                <mx:series>
                    <mx:PieSeries labelPosition="callout" labelField="label" field="data">
                        <mx:fills>
                            <mx:SolidColor color="0x66CC66" />
                            <mx:SolidColor color="0xCC0000" />
                        </mx:fills>             
                    </mx:PieSeries>
                </mx:series>
            </mx:PieChart>

            <mx:PieChart id="_fair" 
                         width.portrait="100%"
                         height.landscape="100%"
                         paddingRight="8" 
                         paddingLeft="8" 
                         dataProvider="{_acFair}" >

                <mx:series>
                    <mx:PieSeries labelPosition="callout" labelField="label" field="data">
                        <mx:fills>
                            <mx:SolidColor color="0x66CC66" />
                            <mx:SolidColor color="0xCC0000" />
                        </mx:fills>             
                    </mx:PieSeries>
                </mx:series>
            </mx:PieChart>  

            <mx:PieChart id="_nice" 
                         width.portrait="100%"
                         height.landscape="100%"
                         paddingRight="8" 
                         paddingLeft="8" 
                         dataProvider="{_acNice}" >

                <mx:series>
                    <mx:PieSeries labelPosition="callout" labelField="label" field="data">
                        <mx:fills>
                            <mx:SolidColor color="0x66CC66" />
                            <mx:SolidColor color="0xCC0000" />
                        </mx:fills>             
                    </mx:PieSeries>
                </mx:series>
            </mx:PieChart>

        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:View>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: When using percent sizes, Flex layout's will make the layout objects no smaller than their minimum size. In this case, the charts seem to think they can be smaller than you like. You might find a crafty way to set the minimumWidth (or height) to a suitable value -- but that may not work so well on different devices.

Comment: I think that, in your vertical view, the pies are of different size because of the callout labels that you have placed in them. Try removing them and showing what each color means in some other way.

Comment: It is very likely to be caused by labels. I had similar issues with cartesian charts, it required some tricky overriding of gutters calculation. You will definitely need some overriding if different `labelPlacement` does not help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place each pie chart inside a container with a set width, then the scroller will become active. I pie charts will always resize small to fit the screen if set to 100%.

B

P.S. the comment above about the pie chart labels is also correct. There is an option to place the labels inside the piechart - PieSeries.labelPosition = inside